# Selenium + Java + Firefox + Windows is not working properly

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I need help with following combination,
OS: Windows 10
Browser used :Firefox 45.0.1
Java version:Java 8 update 51( 64 bit)
Selenium : library 2.47.1
Our code is simple.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.Assert;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TestClass01 
{
    static final Logger logger1 =     LogManager.getLogger(TestClass01.class.getName());

    WebDriver driver ; 
    String baseUrl ;
    static int testCount = 0 ;
    String[] content_heading ;
    List<WebElement> temp_list ;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    boolean exists;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() 
    {
        logger1.entry();
        logger1.info("Entering the class : " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() );

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";

        logger1.info("Maximizing the browser window and setting up the implicit timeout for element/page loading....");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //Specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        logger1.info("Fetching the Homepage for Jacuzzi");

        // launch Firefox and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl+"/");


    }
}
```

However, it throws following error,

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   DEBUG Updating XPIState for
>   {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"BbZlO30v46U7","location":"app-global","version":"45.0.1","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The
>   default
>   theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla
>   Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Mozilla
>   Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1458533973089,"updateDate":1458533973089,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":22012,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"45.0.1","maxVersion":"45.0.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}

Comment: "mostly available online" -- very helpful indeed.

Comment: try downgrading ff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happening because of new issue in latest browser of firefox.

Update your selenium jars. The new version of firefox(Or different browser) is not supporting old jars of selenium.

Download both Selenium Server (formerly the Selenium RC Server) Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings

Replace them with old jars you are using. Update your mozilla also so you can get the updated results

source :- http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

To overcome from this issue you also need to `setPreference` as `xpinstall.signatures.required", false` to firefox Profile and then pass it to driver object

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
```

Below code is working fine for me.

```
static WebDriver driver=null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
driver.get("https://www.google.de/");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working properly after following your advice.